# Ubuntu 12.04 freeze after few seconds in hp touchsmart 520

Tags: 12.04, hp

I have not one but two desktop pc's (hp touchsmart 520). I have been used ubuntu since a long time ago, but something weird happened after upgraded to 12.04. Tne installation process was ok, but when I turn my computer on, after few seconds it (they) freezes and so I have to shut it down. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Try reinstalling grub loader. My computer starts ubuntu 12.04 very slowly, taking more time to boot up than normal. I have to wait to approx. 5 minutes to get to the login. Your problem seems to have issue with either grub loader or maybe the GPU settings.